# Custom ItemDecoration not drawn on last view of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am building an app on android and am using several recyclerviews.

in the first page that i used a recyclerview, everything worked flawlessly and my custom ItemDecoration (divider) was applied to all views.

then i started a new page in which i use the same divider on a similar RecyclerView, but on the last list item the bottom divider is not present.

seeing that it worked perfectly in one place, i don't believe the issue is with the custom ItemDecoration class, nor with the xml. I also tried using the same viewholder for the one that worked, but still the last divider was not drawn.

here is the code where is set up my adapter in the problematic recyclerview:

```
private void setUpPracticesList() {
    lstPractices = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lstPractices);
    lstPractices.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    RecyclerView.Adapter<PracticeHolder> adapter = new RecyclerView.Adapter<PracticeHolder>() {

        String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.practices_names);
        int[] imageIds = {R.drawable.consultation_meeting_icon,
                R.drawable.monitoring_meeting_icon,
                R.drawable.parent_lectures_icon,
                R.drawable.parent_support_groups_icon,
                R.drawable.staff_courses_icon};

        @Override
        public PracticeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.kidsense_practices_list_item, parent, false);

            return new PracticeHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PracticeHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.setName(titles[position]);
            holder.setImage(imageIds[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return titles.length;
        }
    };

    lstPractices.setAdapter(adapter);
    lstPractices.setHasFixedSize(true);
    lstPractices.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), null));
}
```

does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

what i have found is that a recyclerview will not show a divider at the bottom of the last view if there is no more space left in the recyclerview.

in my case, the problem was that my recyclerview was in a layout that had a height of "wrap_content", meaning that there was no extra space left under the recyclerview to display the divider. as soon as i rearranged my layout so that my recyclerview had more space underneath with a parent layout height of "match_parent" the final divider was displayed.